# Udev notification if and only if I plug external monitor

Tags: linux, udev, monitors, multi-monitor, sysfs

I want to send a notification to my application if and only if the user plugs an external monitor (i.e. the connector becames connected).

My output of command `udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/drm/card1-VGA-2`:

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1/card1-VGA-2':
    KERNEL=="card1-VGA-2"
    SUBSYSTEM=="drm"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{edid}==""
    ATTR{dpms}=="On"
    ATTR{enabled}=="enabled"
    ATTR{status}=="connected"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1':
    KERNELS=="card1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="drm"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{gt_RP1_freq_mhz}=="650"
    ATTRS{gt_min_freq_mhz}=="650"
    ATTRS{gt_RPn_freq_mhz}=="650"
    ATTRS{gt_RP0_freq_mhz}=="1300"
    ATTRS{gt_cur_freq_mhz}=="650"
    ATTRS{gt_max_freq_mhz}=="1300"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:02.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="i915"
    ATTRS{irq}=="48"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x17aa"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x030000"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="40"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="40"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,0000000f"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x0126"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}==""
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x21d3"
    ATTRS{boot_vga}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

If my udev rule is the next:

```
KERNEL=="card1", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ATTR{status}=="connected", ACTION=="change",  ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/smidla/.Xauthority", RUN+="/home/smidla/test.sh"
```

nothing happens, but if I remove the `ATTR{status}=="connected"` part, my
`test.sh` executes when I plug and unplug the external monitor.
However,
I need a notification if and only if I connect the monitor. I can not use `xrandr` or reading `/sys/class/drm/card1-VGA-2/status`, because on my hardware these operations slows down the system for some seconds. How can I solve this problem?